# MS Access Combobox if value then set field to date?

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

In MS Access I've got a combo box I setup as "Status". Under Status I have the options:

`0;"Not Started";10;"In Progress";100;"Completed";-10;"Deferred";50;"Waiting"`

What I'm trying to do is set it up so that when "In Progress" is selected my "Date" field is updated with a `Now()` timestamp.
I've attempted to add the following under the validation rule:

`IIf([Status]="In Progress",[StartDate]=Now(),False)`

However, when I change the status to "In Progress" it tells me "The value you entered does not meet the validation rule defined for the field or control. 
But I realized it want's the "In Progress" status to = StartDate NOW() and not to actually change the start date. So I'm at a loss as to where to get this expression in to make it happen.

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!
-Deke

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I didn't realize there was a "On Change" event option for my combo box. After adding a simple IF, Then statement for the event I was able to get this working properly